# Raster aligned but distorted in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, modis

I have mapped a raster image (.tif) from a MODIS image collection in ArcGIS Pro and would like it to align with a polygon (red). However, the image seems to be slanted, which I assume is a projection issue. I've tried using "Define Projection" to transform to WGS1984. The image straightens out but is completely displaced. I've spent the entire day looking for a solution but to no avail.

[image: Screenshot of spatial reference properties]

[image: Screenshot of slanted raster image with polygon]

Comment: Have a look at this [page](https://code.env.duke.edu/projects/mget/wiki/SinusoidalMODIS) and note the transformation used.